# Log message generates some kind of dump if the `tag` has newline in it

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

The code:

```
    Log.d("HelloWorld", "Message");
    Log.d("Hello\nWorld", "Message");
```

The log:

> 06-25 08:43:38.869: D/HelloWorld(18196): Message
>      **06-25 08:43:38.869: D/HelloWorld(18196): [ 06-25 08:43:38.869 18196:0x4714 D/Hello
>
>      06-25 08:43:38.869: D/HelloWorld(18196): World ]**
>      06-25 08:43:38.869: D/HelloWorld(18196): Message

I dug a little with the debugger into `android.util.Log` and the last call before JNI is `println_native`
I am not sure if this is a problem that has to be dealt with or not. 
Currently I have lot of these kind of logs in my actual code and I though that if I can I'll get rid of those weird dumps. Just don't know how.

Comment: Why do you need a new line in `TAG`?

Comment: @shoerat I have more than a few custom buttons on screen, all of the same Class, and I differentiate which one has been clicked by setting the tag on the log messages to "Button" + getText(). Some texts have newlines in them.

Comment: OK, can't you pass that to message? Normally, `TAG` would be a single constant string for whole activity/application but messages will vary. So your `Log` lines should normally be `Log.d("Message", "HelloWorld");` `Log.d("Message", "Hello\nWorld");` "Message" here being `TAG`

Comment: @shoerat I usually have a TAG per class, not per app, it helps me identify where things are happening. And no, it would be a mess for me to change each single message to include the `getText()` there, since sometimes the logs are nested an wrapped. The natural place to put the button name is the TAG for me. Do you know these extra dumps to cause/indicate any problem in the code?